# Using HTML5 and CSS3 to switch 'frames' ever so many seconds like Flash

Tags: html, css, audio, text

I'm wanting to use HTML5 and CSS3 to load an MP3/OGG, and it will read along with text that's being displayed.  As it finishes what's on the screen, it switches to a new screen.

So the first screen would load when the mp3 starts, and stay until 12 seconds(that's how long it takes the voice on the mp3 to read it). At 12 seconds, it switches to the next text, which will stay until 22 seconds. There will be 7 paragraphs in total.

Below is some coding I found of an example, but I can't edit it to work properly with the timing I need.

Basics of the HTML:

```
<audio controls="controls" preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="valmp3.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
    <source src="valmp3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio> 
<ul>
    <li>Paragraph 1</li>
    <!--^^Should load when the mp3 starts and stay for 12 seconds^^-->

    <li>Paragraph 2</li>
    <!--^^Should load at 12 seconds and stay until 22 seconds^^-->

    <li> Paragraph 3</li>

    <li> Paragraph 4</li>

    <li>Paragraph 5</li>

    <li>Paragraph 6</li>

    <li>Paragraph 7</li>
</ul>
```

The CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body{
  background: #422A20;
  font-size: 2em;
}
ul {
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}
ul li {
  color: transparent;
  font-size: 250%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 35%;
  width: 100%;
}

/* delay between each text */
ul li:nth-child(1),
ul li:nth-child(2),
ul li:nth-child(3),
ul li:nth-child(4) {
  -moz-animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
  -ms-animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
  -webkit-animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
}
ul li:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
ul li:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 3s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
ul li:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
ul li:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 9s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 9s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 9s;
  animation-delay: 9s;
}
ul li:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
  animation-delay: 12s;
}
/* delay for the last slide */
ul li:nth-child(5) span {
  -webkit-animation: blurFadeIn 3s ease-in 12s backwards;
  -moz-animation: blurFadeIn 1s ease-in 12s backwards;
  -ms-animation: blurFadeIn 3s ease-in 12s backwards;
  animation: blurFadeIn 3s ease-in 12s backwards;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
}
ul li:nth-child(5) span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 13s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 13s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 13s;
  animation-delay: 13s;
}
ul li:nth-child(5) span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 14s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 14s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 14s;
  animation-delay: 14s;
}
```

Code for the animation:

```
@-moz-keyframes blurFadeInOut {
  0% { opacity: 0; text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff; -moz-transform: scale(1.3); }
  25%, 75% { opacity: 1; text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff; -moz-transform: scale(1); }
  100% { opacity: 0; text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff; -moz-transform: scale(0); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blurFadeInOut {
  0% { opacity: 0; text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff; -webkit-transform: scale(1.3); }
  25%, 75% { opacity: 1; text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff; -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
  100% { opacity: 0; text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff; -webkit-transform: scale(0); }
}
@keyframes blurFadeInOut {
  0% { opacity: 0; text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff; transform: scale(1.3); }
  25%, 75% { opacity: 1; text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff; transform: scale(1); }
  100% { opacity: 0; text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff; transform: scale(0); }
}
```

Comment: You're going to need SOME javascript to detect when the file has been loaded to start the animation so that your timing will match.

Comment: Yes, I'm still trying to figure that out. Above is my current coding, after I get the animation issues fixed I will try to get the javascript loading. So far I'm only testing it on my computer, so the loading times are instant.

Comment: We might need to see the definition(s) of `blurFadeInOut`.

Comment: I edited my post to include the animation code if that's what you meant and a few extra comments about the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're wanting something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/VL3Ub/ (with perhaps different effects)

I reduced it to the simplest form I could.

```
<ul>
    <li>Hello (hello hello hello)</li>
    <li>Is there anybody in there?</li>
    <li>Just nod if you can hear me.</li>
</ul>​
```

CSS

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInOut{
    from,to{opacity:0;}
    25%,75%{opacity:1;}
}

ul li{
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-animation: fadeInOut 4s ease-in;
}

ul li:nth-child(2){
    -webkit-animation-delay:4s;
}
ul li:nth-child(3){
    -webkit-animation-delay:8s;
}
```

So, each li will fade in for 1 second, be visible for 2 seconds, then fade out for 1 second. I then simply stagger the animations by setting the delay `>=` the animation time.

Managing everything might become a little more tricky when accounting for nested animations, but it should follow the same principle.

I'm not sure if this answers your question, or points you in the right direction, so let me know if it doesn't. :)

You can do this to make the animation last longer. I would suggest adjusting the `blurFadeInOut` visible steps to `10%,90%`, or adding a second version of the animation for the longer duration.

```
ul li:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-duration:12s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
}
ul li:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-duration:10s;    
  -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
}
ul li:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 22s;
}
ul li:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 25s;
}
```

Comment: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/NhQTR/ You were spacing the delays out by 3 seconds, even though you wanted it to last for 12 seconds.

Comment: I think this may help. I clarified my original post just now because I read over it and realized I was confusing.  The code I originally posted was just a working example I found.

Comment: @mryoshida check the fiddle in my comment. Is that closer to what you want? Obviously, you may want to adjust the animation keyframes to make the fade-in/fade-out portion shorter/longer.

Comment: Yes this is working out perfectly. Thank you. I now just have to get the CSS working in all browsers then figure out the pre-loading with JavaScript, but I will try to figure that out on my own before I bother you and the rest of StackOverflow again.  Thanks again. Perfect.

Comment: @mryoshida It should be as simple as adding the appropriate vendor prefixes.